# Template base class method template parameter specialization in child class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have an inheritance scheme that looks like this:

```
template <typename CollectionType>
class Sorter {

public:
    virtual void sort(CollectionType &collection) = 0;
};


template <typename ElementType>
class VectorSorter : public Sorter<vector<ElementType>> {
    ...
};
```

Then, I'm adding a fully implemented class that goes like this:

```
template <typename T>
class VectorInsertionSorter : public VectorSorter<T> {

public:
    void sort(vector<T> &collection) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I create a fully specialized `VectorInsertionSorter<int>` through a factory class that is supposed to return a reference to a `VectorSorter<int>`.

This makes it impossible to call the
   `VectorInsertionSorter<int>::sort(vector<int> &collection)` method, which I thought would be dynamically dispatched over `Sorter::sort(CollectionType &collection)`.

Is it possible to provide a method implementation for templated parameters like above, or if I'm doing it wrong how can it be achieved?

Comment: Doesn't really pertain to your question, but `std::sort` already exists. And it works for all standard container types, as well as any container the implements the standard library's iterator abstraction,

Comment: @StoryTeller: `std::sort` doesn't even work for all standard sequences, let alone all standard containers.

Comment: @StoryTeller The sorting itself is a detail, I'm more interested in learning inheritance/generic programming in C++.

Comment: @Fanael - It works for vectors. That's all you need :P

Comment: And sure, it's a detail. But re-implementing the wheel is never a good approach. Nevertheless, like I said, the comment doesn't pertain to your actual question. Just the detail.

Comment: @StoryTeller Actually I'm just doing first examples from Cormen's "Introduction to Algorithms" book and decided to learn a new language along with algorithms. I just sometimes deviate from the algorithms to write something like above, just to get a grip on C++ ;)

Comment: Please give a specific compiler error and enough code for us to throw it at a compiler and see the same error.

Comment: Returning a newly-created object by reference isn't a good idea; you're almost certain to end up with a dangling reference. `unique_ptr` is probably a better choice.